# Enable same origin policy for local files too

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

From a local JS/HTML file I can write stuff like:

```
fetch('http://example.com/my.json').then(...)
```

without having any errors. When I upload the code on a server (e.g. Github pages) I will get the known "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

My question is, how can I **enable** the same origin policy for local files too? That is, I want to get the error when opening local JS/HTML files too.

Everybody wants to disable the same origin policy which makes my research difficult...

The solution can be for either Safari, Chrome or Firefox.